# Why is my MySQL IP address different than physical server IP it is running?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-connection

This may be hugely a dumb question, but I*m a novice to MySQL, and I just discovered that MySQL has different ip i.e. *127.0.0.1* and its hostname (*localhost*) than the machine ip which is *192.168.1.3* and machine hostname is *ceres*, why is it so ?

I connected to MySQL running on different machine using MySQL workbench :

and it shows it logged me to mysql root user to 127.0.0.1 on *pi@192.168.1.3*

[image]

then
[image]

I wanted to insert data to db remotely using arduino MCU and i can definitely not write `127.0.0.1`

Comment: In a terminal, type in `ping ceres` - what does it return? Then, try connecting via IP (vs hostname) - does anything change? In any case, MySQL can (and probably is) bound to different interfaces. The loopback (127.0.0.1) and the machines network interface: both represent connection endpoints to the same MySQL instance.

Comment: I get replies from 192.168.1.3, but I am not able to connect to MySQL using same ip with 3306 port number

Comment: You also need to check that you have correct GRANTs set. `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'IP_address';`. You can check users and hosts that have GRANTs set with `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user`

Comment: run this while logged in as MySQL root;

use mysql;
grant all privileges on */.*/ to 'root'@'%' identified by yourRootPassword;

Do not include the forward slashes but instead type asterisk dot asterisk.

Comment: @JosephMwema  I have commented bind-address that was pointing to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf file

Comment: Do not comment it out but instead replace 127.0.0.1 with 0.0.0.0 to allow external connections other than localhost

Comment: Do not forget to restart MySQL service after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every server is IP 127.0.0.1 to itself. If you want to connect to MySQL installed in a machine where you are logged in, you will use IP 127.0.0.1 or localhost but if you want to connect to MySQL on that machine via another machine, you will have to identify its IP so that you can connect via this IP. That's why remotely you will connect to your MySQL server via IP 192.168.1.3 and not on 127.0.0.1.  localhost is still IP 127.0.0.1

Comment: I just did a google search again with different keywords and found I need to change bind address of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback interface, and is used when you try to connect to the mysql service locally (on the same server where the mysql service is running).

If you need to connect to the mysql service from another machine, you will need its IP address for it. You can use `ifconfig` to see what IP address is assigned to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand a bit about TCP/IP to follow what is going on here. Every TCP/IP stack (implementation) has the internal loopback interface under the address `127.0.0.1` (for IPv4) or `::1` (for IPv6). This makes it easy to access the stack on the local machine without knowning it's TCP/IP address (or even if it has got none).

Then each machine participating in a TCP/IP network needs an address under which it is known in this network (in your case `192.168.1.3`). When you work on your local machine then it doesn't matter if you use it's public IP address or it's loopback interface. A third option is the name `localhost` which resolves to the loopback interface. But watch out: it depends on the OS if that ends up at the IPv4 or the IPv6 variant.

As you know you can specify a host for a user, which decides from which it can connect. And here `user@localhost` and `user@127.0.0.1` (or `user@::1`) are **not** the same host. The MySQL terminal implicitly treats localhost and loopback IP address as the same, for the user's convenience, but other clients do not. The bind address mentioned here is usually not involved at all. This is for special scenarios not relevant here. In over 10 years I never had to set a bind address for MySQL.

**Update**: I hope that downvoters comment on their action to show if something needs to be improved in my answer or they are just ignorant.